# Querystring is added in javascript bundles in asp.net mvc 4 when optimization disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I am debugging the application.SO Just disabled the bundles in **global.asax**

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Even though the querystring is added to the script url

```
http://localhost:82/Scripts/ProgramView/OrderOffering/Order-Tab-Common.js?_=1392983430969
```

Comment: How are you referencing the bundle?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is to make the js-file download every time you reload the page, since the id will be changed and the browser will assume that it's a different resource and won't take it from the cache.

This is good, since you don't need to clear your browsers cache every time you make changes to the js file

Comment: Yes it is right.But I dont want to refresh every time.How can i disable that.Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think that is possible, can I ask for the purpose, why you want to do it?

Comment: May i know, where or why this querystring is added to the url.The reason is i wanted the js to be cached to debugging purpase.